# How do I ignore some characters when getting date from string using NSDateFormater? Also, is there any reference for NSDateFormatter?

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

My problem is simple. I have strings in the format "16th Sep 2015"

When generating the date string, I used the NSDateFormatter as "d MMM yyyy" and then manually modified it to insert the date suffixes using a switch case.

Now, I need to extract date again.

Is there any way to ignore those 2 letters?

Also, I have been learning NSDateFormatter by using Google and just following posts like [this](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime#TOC-DateTimePatternGenerator) but all my questions are not answered and sometimes, there is a mismatch in behaviour described.

Is there a standard reference by Apple where the Date Formatter codes are described?

Comment: can you explain with example? Because I can't understand your issue.

Comment: checkout my answer and dont forget to upvote :)

Comment: `NSString *dateString = @"2nd Oct 2015";  
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];  
[formatter setDateFormat: "..................."];  
[formatter dateFromString:dateString];`    What comes in the blank?

Comment: There are multiple correct answers submitted and though I can't mark all of them, I am thankful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSDateformatter` does not support days with ordinal indicators, but you could use a regular expression to strip the indicators

```
var dateString = "16th Sep 2015"
if let range = dateString.range(of: "(st|nd|rd|th)", options: .regularExpression) {
    dateString.removeSubrange(range)
}    
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
let date = formatter.date(from: dateString)!
print(date)
```

Or in Objective-C

```
NSMutableString *dateString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"16th Sep 2015"];

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(st|nd|rd|th)" options:nil error:nil];
[regex replaceMatchesInString:dateString options: nil range: NSMakeRange(0, 4) withTemplate:@""];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"d MMM yyyy";
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

Comment: it fails if the Date format is 01st August 2015. its remove both "st" and further logic gets affected.

Comment: @Mansur Just replace the `replacingOccurrences` line with `if let range = dateString.range(of: "(st|nd|rd|th)", options: .regularExpression) { dateString.removeSubrange(range) }`. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't the prettiest of solutions but it can work:

```
NSString *dateString = @"1st Sep 2015";

dateString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"st " withString:@" "];
dateString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"nd " withString:@" "];
dateString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"rd " withString:@" "];
dateString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"th " withString:@" "];

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.dateFormat = @"d MMM yyyy";

NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: Yea, in a way I did something like that.

I searched for the white space character and the first removed 2 characters before that. As I mentioned in Markus's answer.

I guess there is no other way. Thanks for all the help and patience :)

Answer (score 1):

Only a partial answer, I am afraid, but Apple essentially implements this specification: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

The specification does suggest something called "Lenient parsing" that allows the parser to ignore some extraneous characters, but at least as defined in the standard, this doesn't seem to extend to your particular case. So it certainly looks like you have to manually remove the suffix from the day number before handing the string to the parser, unless it happens to "just work", which I don't think it does.

Comment: Since I use d and not dd, I initially thought I would have trouble removing it, but just as I inserted it, I can search and get the range of white spaces and delete 2 characters just before the start position of the space.

I was hoping to find a way through date formatter though. I'll check out the lenient parsing.

Looks promising. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

While the will work if you have a month that is 3 letters, it will not work if you have the full month. For example, "Augu" will turn into "August" Using Regular Expressions, you can check for a digit to be before the letters by doing the following:

```
var dateString = "16th Sep 2015"
//regular expression using positive look behind. Checks for a digit, than a two letter combination that will match below
dateString = dateString.replacingOccurrences(of: "(?<=\\d)[snrt][tdh]", with: "", options: String.CompareOptions.regularExpression, range: nil)

let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "d MMM yyyy" //if full month, add extra M
df.date(from: dateString)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code with CORRECT date format that will be your angel:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.dateFormat = @"d'th' MMM yyyy";

NSString *stringDate = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

//output -- 16th Sep 2015
```

Now you can use this dateformatter to convert to and from `NSDate` object.

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry but this won't work for me

1. this code will result in dates such as 1th. (Yes, I have checked before replying)

2. I wanted to get date from string, not string from date. 
Had the formatter been correct though, this is not really a problem as it should work both ways.

Thank you for answering though